# Date formatting CSV MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have imported a series of CSV files into MySQL. The date columns are all formatting like:

```
1152015
12242014
12292014
1072015
1142015
1152015
1142015
1142015
1052015
12232014
1062015
12222014
1052015
```

`STR_TO_DATE(colName, '%m/%d/%Y')` does not work and returns only nulls. How can I format these to a date?

Comment: So, if you were to encounter `1112015` – would that be the 11th of January, or the 1st of November …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that leading zeros are missing from the format.  Then, you should use the right format string:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT(CONCAT('0', colName), 8), '%m%d%Y')
```

Alternatively, you could construct the date string by pieces:

```
SELECT DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', right(colName, 4), left(right(colname, 6), 2),
                      left(right(concat('0', colname), 8), 2)
                     )
           )
```

Comment: these are all great solutions but this is the best for what i need, thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need to convert directly in the query, but if you want to work  with the column in PHP instead of mysql, you may do this in a loop:

```
<?php
    $matches = array();
    preg_match("%([0-9]{2})([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{4})%","12292014", $matches);
    $date = $matches[1] . '/' . $matches[2] . '/' . $matches[3];
    var_dump($date);
```

I used "12292014" but you just need to change this for your iterating value.

(See in action [here](https://eval.in/303093))

Answer (score 0):

This could be `'%m%e%Y'` format ( `'mjY'` in PHP ), since leading zeros are missing, php and mysql are having problems to automatically convert this.

php solution ( convert string to `'mj-Y'` and use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) ):

```
$d = '1072015';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'mj-Y', sprintf( '%s-%s', substr( $d, 0, -4 ), substr( $d, -4 ) ) );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

mysql solution ( convert to `'%m%e-%Y'` ):

```
STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( LEFT( column, LENGTH(column) - 4 ), '-', RIGHT( postTitle, 4 ) ), '%m%e-%Y' )
```

It could also be `'%c%e%Y'` format, and then things are getting more complicated.